# Trying to run a scrapy crawler from another location within script

Tags: python, twisted, scrapy

All,

I'm trying to fully automate my scraping, which is formed by 3 steps:

1- Get the list of index pages for advertisements (Non-scrapy work, for various reasons)
2- Get the list of advertisement URLs from the index pages obtained in step one (Scrapy work)

My scrapy project is in the usual directory:

C:\Python27\Scripts\GetAdUrlsFromIndex_project\GetAdUrlsFromIndex\spiders\GetAdUrls_spider.py
(name of the spider inside the "GetAdUrls_spider" file is (name = "getadurls"))

My script to automate the step 1 and 2 is in this directory:

C:\Website_DATA\SCRIPTS\StepByStepLauncher.py

I have tried using the Scrapy documentation to import the crawler and run from inside the script using the following code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy import log
from GetAdUrlsFromIndex.spiders.GetAdUrls_spider import getadurls

spider = getadurls(domain='website.com')
crawler = Crawler(Settings())
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run() # the script will block here
```

I keep getting the error "No module named GetAdUrlsFromIndex.spiders.GetAdUrls_spider" when I try to run this script unfortunately.. I tried changing working directory to several few different locations, I played around with names, nothing seemed to work..

Would appreciate any help.. Thanks!

Comment: Is `C:\Python27\Scripts\GetAdUrlsFromIndex_project\` in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Hi Twil... I actually didnt have a PYTHONPATH variable at all!!. I created one and added this one, but still doesnt work...

Comment: Do folders `GetAdUrlsFromIndex` and `spiders` contain `__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes they do twil... Both folders contain a __init__.py.. However they are both blank. Do I need to include anything in them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you do have `__init__.py` in `C:\Python27\Scripts\GetAdUrlsFromIndex_project\GetAdUrlsFromIndex` and `C:\Python27\Scripts\GetAdUrlsFromIndex_project\GetAdUrlsFromIndex\spiders` then try modifying your script this way

```
import sys
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy import log

sys.path.append('C:/Python27/Scripts/GetAdUrlsFromIndex_project')
from GetAdUrlsFromIndex.spiders.GetAdUrls_spider import getadurls

spider = getadurls(domain='website.com')
crawler = Crawler(Settings())
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run() # the script will block here
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you have `No module named ...` it's basically problem with `PYTHONPATH` and could be "healed" this way. PS: accept answer by the way;)

Comment: is there a solution where we would not have to append the system path?

Comment: @DaveTheAl if your case is the same as in the question then you somehow have to tell `python` where your main code (`C:/Python27/Scripts/GetAdUrlsFromIndex_project`) is. If you can move your main code then put it in `site-packages`, e.g. `C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages`.

Comment: thanks! is there also something similar to `python -m` which fixates the path, or something to `PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) python main.py`?

Comment: @DaveTheAl sorry I don't get the question